# mpdf creating issue while applying width in px to td of table row

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I am using mpdf in PHP and facing issue when passing width in px to td of table. in Percentage it is working fine but when the content increases or decreases it is not symmetric in all pdfs.

**This is the issue in PDF**
[image: PDF Issue]

**Check below HTML echo of the same.**
[image]

Comment: Well just use 1 table instead of 2?

Comment: so instead of tables I should go with single table and all tr structures ?